# Divide numpy array into multiple arrays using indices array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 29 ... 5030, 6000]
```

This array gets created from a previous process, and the length of the array could be different (it is depending on user input).

I also have an array:

```
b = [3, 15, 67, 78, 138]
```

(Which could also be completely different)

I want to use the array `b` to slice the array `a` into multiple arrays.

More specifically, I want the result arrays to be:

```
array1 = a[:3]
array2 = a[3:15]
...
arrayn = a[138:]
```

Where `n = len(b)`.

My first thought was to create a 2D array `slices` with dimension `(len(b), something)`. However we don't know this `something` beforehand so I assigned it the value `len(a)` as that is the maximum amount of numbers that it could contain.

I have this code:

```
 slices = np.zeros((len(b), len(a)))

 for i in range(1, len(b)):
     slices[i] = a[b[i-1]:b[i]]
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (518) into shape (2253412)
```

Comment: I'm surprised I couldn't find a duplicate question. Good work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [numpy.split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
np.split(a, b)
```

*Example*:

```
np.split(np.arange(10), [3,5])
# [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
b.insert(0,0)
result = []
for i in range(1,len(b)):
    sub_list = a[b[i-1]:b[i]]
    result.append(sub_list)
result.append(a[b[-1]:])
```

Comment: This is essentially what `np.split` does, with a little fancier footwork to allow split on other axis.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you are attempting to create a ragged array. This is not allowed in numpy.

An improvement on @Bohdan's answer:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
result = [a[start:end] for start, end in zip_longest(np.r_[0, b], b)]
```

The trick here is that `zip_longest` makes the final slice go from `b[-1]` to `None`, which is equivalent to `a[b[-1]:]`, removing the need for special processing of the last element.

Please do not select this. This is just a thing I added for fun. The "correct" answer is @Psidom's answer.